# Database Normalization Advice

Tags: performance, database-design, normalization

I have database for multi store application. So, I have 3 type of user thats Admin, Customer, Merchant and I have 3 table for users. User table, Customer table, Merchant table.

User Table;

```
id
username
name
password
email
status
city_id
state_id
role_id
...
```

Customer Table;

```
id
taxNumber
cart_id
user_id
```

Merchant Table;

```
id
taxNumber
commission
user_id
```

So, there is a 1:0 relationship between merchant/customer tables and user table. I want a 1:1 relationship but if I do this, I have to create columns like customer_id and merchant_id and if customer_id is not null then merchant_id will be null or merchant_id is not null then customer_id will be null in user table. Is it bad for normalization?

Comment: How is this not just asking for yet another presentation of normalization from absolute scratch? Please follow a textbook & ask 1 specific question where you are 1st stuck. See [help] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS Normalization has nothing to say about FKs or NULLs. PS [What to do with null values when modeling and normalizing?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40733625/3404097)

Answer (score 1):

With the current design you could have several customers with the same user_id (similarly for merchants). This is a one-to-many association. To solve this problem, simply do not introduce `id` for table `customers`, but use `user_id` as primary key for it, in addition to it being a foreign key for table `users`. Then you can have only one customer for user. Similarly for table `merchants`.

Then you can enforce the constraint that users cannot exists without either being a customer or a merchant by defining in your application  functions to create customers or merchants, but not users. Those functions will create the appropriate rows. Finally, is up to you to decide if a customer can be also a merchant or not. In both cases, the function to create the customer or the merchant must take appropriate action.